# Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to add margin top to `class="row"` elements using twitter bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 833, accepted):

Editing or overriding the row in Twitter bootstrap is a bad idea, because this is a core part of the page scaffolding and you will need rows without a top margin.

To solve this, instead create a new class "top-buffer" that adds the standard margin that you need.

```
.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
```

And then use it on the row divs where you need a top margin.

```
<div class="row top-buffer"> ...
```

Comment: Nielsen says both to use a new class or to edit the native .row ... you are replicating i think :P

Comment: Editing the native row is wrong for a framework, and the new class should just complement the row class...it is a subtle difference but in Twitter Bootstrap the row has a specific page layout role.  Anyway, I'm just trying to help, my solution is a working one for the problem.

Comment: no way, these answers are slightly different IMHO. This one is more usable as it embraces the "name your class style so your html reads easier" and you can read margin-top in the html instead of rowSpecificForName.  This answer is more inline with twitter bootstrap patterns.

Comment: They're going to add specific vertical spacing classes into Bootstrap 4: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4286

Comment: All I learned from these comments is that developers are very opinionated and some prefer 2 + 3 = 5 and others 3 + 2 = 5.  Moving on...

Comment: @FabioS. What should be learned is that for a framework like Bootstrap, editing the native code or overwriting it is a bad idea. The scenarios are endless but here are a couple examples. a.) overwriting - if you overwrite the .row class you now need to go through your project and add an additional class to rows that shouldn't receive the margin b.) editing native code - you inherit a project at work and you want to move up to bootstrap4; OOPS! Nothing looks right!? Now you have the burden of going through the bootstrap 3 file trying to find what on earth the previous developer altered.

Comment: terrible answer, it is not encapsulating the css change by calling something from bootstrap framework itself.

Answer (score 187):

Ok just to let you know what's happened then, i fixed using some new classes as Acyra says above:

```
.top5 { margin-top:5px; }
.top7 { margin-top:7px; }
.top10 { margin-top:10px; }
.top15 { margin-top:15px; }
.top17 { margin-top:17px; }
.top30 { margin-top:30px; }
```

whenever i want i do `<div class="row top7"></div>`

for better responsive you can add `margin-top:7%` instead of `5px` for example :D

Comment: I feel that this solution is much more elegant than the accepted solution.

Comment: @alexander but more generic.

Comment: How is `.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }` different from `.top30 { margin-top:30px; }`? Well, from the point of any developer: It is the same. Adjustemts to fit the use case do not count here. Specially not, if the OP answered his own question.

Comment: clearly the most generic solution would be to manipulate the DOM from javascript to dynamically change the class or the style...

Comment: The classic 17px top margin; Very useful.

Answer (score 187):

## Bootstrap 3

If you need to separate rows in bootstrap, you can simply use `.form-group`. This adds 15px  margin to the bottom of row.

In your case, to get margin top, you can add this class to previous `.row` element

```
<div class="row form-group">

/* From bootstrap.css */
.form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

## Bootstrap 4

You can use built-in [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/#notation)

```
<div class="row mt-3"></div>
```

The "t" in class name makes it apply only to "top" side, there are similar classes for bottom, left, right. The number defines space size.

Comment: Was form-group stripped from BS4?

Comment: No, [`form-group` is still present](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1990), but special classes for margin/padding has been added that can do the job and has more options.

Comment: Have there been multiple changes to this in Bootstrap V 4? I'm on a version of 4 now and `mt-3` does not work so used `form-group`

Comment: [It should work](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/8nybvmzd/), check if bootstrap css you linked to your project contains ".mt-3" class definition.

Answer (score 96):

For **Bootstrap 4** spacing should be applied using

> shorthand utility classes

in the following format:

> {property}{sides}-{size}

Where ***property*** is one of:

- m - for classes that set margin
- p - for classes that set padding

Where ***sides*** is one of:

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
- r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
- blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

Where ***size*** is one of:

- 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
- 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
- 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
- 3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
- 4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
- 5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
- auto - for classes that set the margin to auto

So you should be doing any of these:

```
<div class="row mt-1">
<div class="row mt-2">
          ...
<div class="row mt-5">
```

Read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) for more explanation.
Try live examples over [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_util_spacing&stacked=h).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now with the release of Bootstrap 4. It comes with these built-in classes, no need to create new ones.

Answer (score 44):

Sometimes margin-top can causes design problems:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

So, i recommend create "margin-bottom classes" instead of "margin-top classes" and apply them to the previous item.

If you are using Bootstrap importing LESS Bootstrap files try to define the margin-bottom classes with proportional Bootstrap Theme spaces:

```
.margin-bottom-xs {margin-bottom: ceil(@line-height-computed / 4);}  
.margin-bottom-sm {margin-bottom: ceil(@line-height-computed / 2);} 
.margin-bottom-md {margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;}
.margin-bottom-lg {margin-bottom: ceil(@line-height-computed * 2);}
```

Answer (score 32):

I added these classes to my bootstrap stylesheet

```
.voffset  { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset1 { margin-top: 5px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 15px; }
.voffset4 { margin-top: 30px; }
.voffset5 { margin-top: 40px; }
.voffset6 { margin-top: 60px; }
.voffset7 { margin-top: 80px; }
.voffset8 { margin-top: 100px; }
.voffset9 { margin-top: 150px; }
```

Example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row voffset2">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <p>
        Vertically offset text.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26):

I'm using these classes to alter top margin:

```
.margin-top-05 { margin-top: 0.5em; }
.margin-top-10 { margin-top: 1.0em; }
.margin-top-15 { margin-top: 1.5em; }
.margin-top-20 { margin-top: 2.0em; }
.margin-top-25 { margin-top: 2.5em; }
.margin-top-30 { margin-top: 3.0em; }
```

When I need an element to have 2em spacing from the element above I use it like this:

```
<div class="row margin-top-20">Something here</div>
```

If you prefere pixels so change the em to px to have it your way.

Comment: Good idea, but I abstract away the numbers, as they are too specific. If you stick with abstractions like s, m, l, xl, xxl, etc, you can change the sizes via css without having to change names in templates.

Comment: @MikePurcell Good thought and it may be the right solution for you. But I prefer a more exact way to define margins. Using em instead of px gives me a loose way to achieve it without getting too specific.

Comment: What's the benefit of `<div class="row margin-top-20">` over `<div class"row" style="margin-top: 2.0em">`?

Comment: @icc97 Basically, separate of concerns, but here you can see other opinions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612494/1683224.

Comment: @WileyMarques That's true for a class named e.g. "top-buffer" (as in the accepted answer), but doesn't make sense for a class named margin-top-20. Unless you're happy for margin-top-20 to actually add something other than 2ems of padding, which would just be confusing.

Comment: @Hexodus then the class name would have no meaning. As others point out, having sensible class names like `xs`, `sm` etc. makes sense, but when your class name is so completely tied to the style name as in this answer the whole point of classes goes away. Why don't you just call the class `margin-top-2.0em` instead of `margin-top-20`? At what point does this all become pointless and we all just accept that we should all just have been taken up flower arranging instead?

Comment: @icc97 This is used for fine adjusting certain elements and not for global changes. Some people including me are preferring this approach as you can see from the class name what it's doing. You can as well have global classes. but inline style is never a good idea. Css classes are reusable and are there to separate the styling from the content.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following class for bootstrap 4:

`mt-0`
`mt-1`
`mt-2`
`mt-3`
`mt-4`
...

Ref: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 4 alpha, for margin-top: shorthand CSS class names mt-1, mt-2 ( mt-lg-5, mt-sm-2) 
same for the bottom, right, left, and you have also auto class ml-auto

```
    <div class="mt-lg-1" ...>
```

Units are from `1` to `5` :  in the variables.scss 
which means if you set mt-1 it gives .25rem of margin top.

```
$spacers: (
  0: (
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  ),
  1: (
    x: ($spacer-x * .25),
    y: ($spacer-y * .25)
  ),
  2: (
    x: ($spacer-x * .5),
    y: ($spacer-y * .5)
  ),
  3: (
    x: $spacer-x,
    y: $spacer-y
  ),
  4: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 1.5),
    y: ($spacer-y * 1.5)
  ),
  5: (
    x: ($spacer-x * 3),
    y: ($spacer-y * 3)
  )
) !default;
```

read-more here

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Answer (score 3):

Add to this class in the .css file:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -20px;
    *zoom: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

or make a new class and add it to the element

```
.rowSpecificFormName td {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: uhmmmmm i don't like totouch the css , what if i need rows with no margin in other pages?

Comment: You could make a new class .rowSpecificForm

Comment: But there is no defined css class for only 'margin-top' in Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: strange they didn't setted few class forspacing vertically, i need to add them there is no other solution :/, thanks Nielsen

Comment: remember CSS cascades, so you'll never have to edit bootstrap.css.

Comment: This is not a good way to do it, Since its accepted people may follow it but i suggest using less for bootstrap and define margin otherwise look at my answer below.

Comment: Overriding framework specific code is not a good approach because it will lead to strange code behavior and will make it more difficult to debug your own code.

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 alpha+ you can use this

```
class margin-bottom-5
```

The classes are named using the format: `{property}-{sides}-{size}`

Answer (score 2):

```
just take a new class beside every row and apply css of margin-top: 20px;
here is the code below
<style>
  .small-top
   {
     margin-top: 25px;  
   }
</style>    
<div class="row small-top">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer. Answering without explanations is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap3

CSS (gutter only, without margins around):

```
.row.row-gutter {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row.row-gutter > *[class^="col"] {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

CSS (equal margins around, 15px/2):

```
.row.row-margins {
  padding-top: 7px; /* or margin-top: 7px; */
  padding-bottom: 7px; /* or margin-bottom: 7px; */
}
.row.row-margins > *[class^="col"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class="row row-gutter">
    <div class="col col-sm-9">first</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">second</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-12">third</div>
</div>
```

(with SASS or LESS 15px could be a variable from bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row row-padding">
```

simple code

Comment: using bootstrap - 4 you can add this class to make the spacing between row

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change just on one page, add the following style rule:

```
 #myCustomDivID .row {
     margin-top:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick for adding margin **automatically** only for the 2nd+ row in the container.

```css
.container-row-margin .row + .row {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Adding the `.container-row-margin` to the container, results in:

[image]

Complete HTML:

```html
<div class="bg-secondary text-white">
    div outside of the container.
</div>
<div class="container container-row-margin">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-4 bg-warning">
            Row without top margin
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-4 bg-primary text-white">
            Row with top margin
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-4 bg-primary text-white">
            Row with top margin
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-secondary text-white">
    div outside of the container.
</div>
```

Taken from official [samples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width).

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 5**

In Bootstrap 5 you could do something like this:

```
<div class="row mt-X"></div>
```

where X is a number from 0 (no space) to 5 (a lot of space). For more information on the different margin/padding sizes and the breakpoint specific control, please have a look at the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code :

```
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this **`bs3-upgrade`** helper for spacings and text aligment...

https://github.com/studija/bs3-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BootStrap 3.3.7, you can use the open source library bootstrap-spacer via NPM

```
npm install bootstrap-spacer
```

or you can visit the github page:

```
https://github.com/chigozieorunta/bootstrap-spacer
```

Here's an example of how this works to space rows using the .row-spacer class:

```
<div class="row row-spacer">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row row-spacer">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you'd require spaces between columns, you can also add the .row-col-spacer class:

```
<div class="row row-col-spacer">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can also combine various the .row-spacer & .row-col-spacer classes together:

```
<div class="row row-spacer row-col-spacer">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would advise against adding a dependency for 40 lines of css

Answer (score -5):

My trick. Not so clean, but works well for me

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```