# change size of login form and space between inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.
I want to make login form smaller and change size between input because now they are too close.

Here my code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2 well col-lg-5">
        <legend>Please Sign In</legend>
        <!--<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            Incorrect Username or Password!
        </div>-->
        <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user input-group-addon"></span>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control input-medium" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="${userName}">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock input-group-addon"></span>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="${pass}">
        </div>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember Me
        </label>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign in</button>
        </form>    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How to do it?

Form

[image]

Comment: can you post your css??

Comment: I use default bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W9JdV/9/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to constrain the entire form you can set a few CSS rules like these, which will also enable you to move the form position on the screen or add padding around the entire form (or parts of it: IE the top/bottom).

You can use a rule like this to change the margin between fields `#loginForm .input-group`.

```
.formCenter {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.formCenter.formChange {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 50px;
}
#loginForm .input-group {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
@media (max-width : 768px) {
    .formCenter.formChange {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here's a Working example:

```css
.formCenter {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.formCenter.formChange {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 50px;
}
#loginForm .input-group {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .formCenter.formChange {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="formCenter formChange">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 well">
        <legend>Please Sign In</legend>
        <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="loginForm">
          <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" name='username' id="username" placeholder="Username" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>

            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name='password' placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">Remember Me</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the grid system you can make them smaller bigger whatever. See below. For spaces between them [Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows) . Have fun!

```
<div class="container">
              <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if redirect_field_value %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                {% endif %}
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="id_login" name="login" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                        <input id="id_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="id_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="id_password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
                </div>
              </form>
        </div>
```