# Bootstrap 3 - Column top margin on smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have a row with X possible columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">content</div>
        <!-- ... and so on ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to add `margin-top:20px` to all small screen columns and the same margin for big screen columns, if there are more than 4 as that would cause two "rows" to be shown and would therefore require some space between.

Is that somehow possible with only the use of CSS?

Comment: First of all, you can't have any number of columns in one row, as you wish. Sum of all column classes in one row must be twelve. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: Not true @MiljanPuzović, the columns simply begin a new line once they run out of space. Otherwise how would a row full of `col-xs-12` work?

Comment: @n00b, `col-sx-6` should be `col-xs-6`

Comment: It works, but it's not correct by docs.

Comment: It's fundamental to how a responsive framework works!

Comment: Ok, you know better than creators of bootstrap :)

Comment: It's exactly how the creators of bootstrap intended it.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic Every row have the sum of twelve cols. Show me just one example in official docs where sum is greater of twelve in case of twelve grid system.

Comment: Wrong link :http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed.

Comment: Ok, now look above and tell me where is .container-fluid class.

Comment: Not the link, see OP's question and markup.

Comment: No, to your previous question, I posted the wrong link. Check the markup and count the numbers. If you are coding a fully responsive ie.  making full use of all the breakpoints in bootrap's css, all column numbers below large size will add up to more than twelve. In such a case, columns will simply start a new line. As designed.

Comment: Hm, maybe you are right. My bad.

Comment: Probably I still live in bootstrap 2 period.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a media query for whenever you want the top margin..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xs-6 {
        margin-top:20px;
    }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/126007

P.S. - There is nothing wrong with having the total of `.col-*` in a `.row` exceeding 12 (ie: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed). It simply causes a wrap. There are several examples in the docs that use this technique. It's generally not ideal for nested rows.

Comment: Shouldn't the media query be "max-width: 767px", since Bootstrap 3's .col-sm applies to "≥768px"?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that there should be a better solution (a margin class http://stackoverflow.com/a/20096216/2219831 ) probably. In order to add vertical space between items, the **content editor** will have to edit CSS. Also there could be a scenario where not all stacked elements would need vertical spacing.

Comment: Ya, the margin class would work too, and there is something like this in the upcoming Bootstrap 4. However, the margin class does'nt work for a specific grid tier/breakpoint like this solution. Generally content is contained within another element (ie: <p>) which would also provide spacing.

Answer (score 7):

I needed something similar and following is the solution I came up with. Documenting it for future readers (and myself)

```
$res-list: (xs: (0px, 767px), sm: (768px, 991px), md: (992px, 1199px), lg: (1200px, 9999px));
$dir-list: (t: top, r: right, b: bottom, l: left);

@for $r from 1 through 10{
  @each $res-abbr, $res-vals in $res-list{
    @media (min-width: nth($res-vals, 1)) and (max-width: nth($res-vals, 2)) {
      @each $dir-abbr, $dir-name in $dir-list{
        $x: $r * 5;
        .m#{$dir-abbr}-#{$res-abbr}-#{$x}{
          margin-#{$dir-name}: #{$x}px;
        }
        .m#{$dir-abbr}-#{$res-abbr}-#{$r}p{
          margin-#{$dir-name}: #{$r}unquote('%');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This SASS code generates classes along the lines of following

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mt-xs-5 { margin-top: 5px; }
    .mt-xs-1p { margin-top: 1%; }
    .mr-xs-5 { margin-right: 5px; }
    .mr-xs-1p { margin-right: 1%; }
    .mb-xs-5 { margin-bottom: 5px; }
    .mb-xs-1p { margin-bottom: 1%; }
    .ml-xs-5 { margin-left: 5px; }
    .ml-xs-1p { margin-left: 1%; } 
}
```

So the content editor can use `.mt-xs-10` to apply `margin-top: 10px` to given element on `extra-small` screen.

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: You should be congratulated for massively over-complicating a simple task.

Comment: I would not think it as being over-complicated but being empowering to the content editors. Think about the usage of resulting CSS rules.

Comment: Interesting ressource, for small projects it is overcomplicating thinks but for larger ones(repeated simple tasks)  it is smarter and more simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but below is a clean solution.

```
[class*="col-"] {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This works well for some situations but it adds extra, unnecessary margin when it's not needed.
To solve this, we can create a new css class that applies top margin to columns when they get stacked. I create a class named `.row-grid`

```
.row.row-grid [class*="col-"] + [class*="col-"] {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row.row-grid [class*="col-lg-"] + [class*="col-lg-"] {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row.row-grid [class*="col-md-"] + [class*="col-md-"] {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.row-grid [class*="col-sm-"] + [class*="col-sm-"] {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple and clean solution:

```
.row { margin-top: -15px; }
.row > div { margin-top: 15px; }
```

In that manner, every `<div class='col-*-*'>` has 15px margin on top, except those on the first row (or, on mobile, except the one on the top).

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution automatically applies a top margin to all columns except the first, at extra small screen sizes. No special class names or other modifications to HTML or CSS are necessary. (Change the `margin-top` value below to whatever you prefer.)

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  [class*="col-"]:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```