# What tag controls the spacing and where to put it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

My form is marked up using bootstrap. It renders more or less as I intended, but there's no space between the input groups, as illustrated below. The data-binding attributes are knockout syntax, but I don't think they matter one way or the other for the purposes of this question.

```
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-search"></i>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="foo NEAR bar" 
             data-bind="value: predicate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-step-backward"></i>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" 
             data-bind="datepicker: { value: a, dateFormat: 'd MM yy' }" />
    </div>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-step-forward"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" 
               data-bind="datepicker: { value: b, dateFormat: 'd MM yy' }" />
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg pull-right">
        <span class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></span>
        <span class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here we see the result of the above mark-up.

[image: Rendered form]

Bootstrap is pretty comprehensive, so I imagine there are tags for controlling this, but the documentation is a terse run of samples and I haven't found anything similar enough to clue me in.

Often bootstrap is quite cleverly constructed so that a single class applied to (say) the parent div will apply in various ways to all the children. So, what tag do I need and where ought I place it in order to get interstitial spacing for the input groups?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows

Comment: It's almost but not quite the same question. Write an answer that says Bootstrap does not have a class for this and that a workaround may be found in that question. Then I'll accept it. As it happens I already took the approach of creating and applying my own class, I just figured I was probably duplicating some Bootstrap class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that applies a margin between groups in a form is `.form-group`.  [Bootstrap says](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms):

> Do not mix form groups directly with input groups. Instead, nest the
>   input group inside of the form group.

So in your case:

**Normal form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-search"></i>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="foo NEAR bar" data-bind="value: predicate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

The only problem here is that you are using `.form-horizontal`.  When you do that, Bootstrap applies a negative left and right margin to the `.form-control` because it expects you to arrange your fields using `.col-xs-4` (or whatever).  So I suggest either you don't use that `.form-horizontal` class in the form, or you add a col-* class to fix the negative margin:

**Horizontal form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-search"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="foo NEAR bar" 
               data-bind="value: predicate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[Demo(s)](http://jsbin.com/xokug/1/edit)**

Comment: Just the answer I wanted. I'm accepting it anyway but I hope you'll add a link to the documentation you're quoting.

Comment: Glad to have helped!  I just placed the link in (if you click 'Bootstrap says:').  It takes you to Bootstrap forms but it's only a small amount further down the page in a yellow warning box.