# In Bootstrap 3,How to change the distance between rows in vertical?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two rows a and b,I think the distance between the two rows in vertical is too small.

I want to make the distance more bigger,I know I can change the distance in horizontal by col-md-offset-*.But how to change the vertical distance?

```
   <div class="row" id="a">
      <img> ... </img>
    <div>
    <div class="row" id="b">
      <button>..</button>
    <div>
```

Now my solution is insert a tag of h1,I think it is not graceful.

```
   <div class="row" id="a">
      <img> ... </img>
    <div>
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="row" id="b">
      <button>..</button>
    <div>
```

Does it have more graceful solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows)

Answer (score 33):

Instead of adding any tag which is never a good solution. You can always use `margin` property with the required element.

You can add the margin on row class itself. So it will affect globally.

```
.row{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
```

**Update**: *Better solution in all cases would be to introduce a new class and then use it along with `.row`* class.

```
.row-m-t{
  margin-top : 20px
}
```

Then use it wherever you want

```
<div class="row row-m-t"></div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't edit the `.row` class like this since `.row` is used throughout bootstrap 3.  Better to create a new class like `.row-margin`

Comment: Yes @Dan I agreed to your point but this is all depend on the requirement. If I want to every row class then I would use it, otherwise I will create new. btw it's just an example..

Comment: I don't think define row css is  good idea,Why not bootstrap give a better solution,they have already define the col-md-offset,why not define rol-md-offset-* again?

Comment: modifying the row class is an anti-pattern since it is a fundamental part of bootstrap scaffolding. create a css class for the purpose or use other bootstrap classes that add vertical margin for example form-group.

Comment: I totally agree with you Dan.  You can go even further and do custom css class names like .row-margin-sm, .row-margin-md, .row-margin-lg, etc.. and just plug them in where needed.  It does no harm to the original bootstrap framework - they are simply custom helper classes.

Comment: What if I'm using a CDN for bootstrap :)

Comment: @Sorter you can add an additional style declaration or even inline CSS

Answer (score 31):

use:

```
<div class="row form-group"></div>
```

Comment: can't believe this, adding margin could be so hard, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. It always bothered me how the docs would show the grid layout with spacing between the rows, but that's not how it actually is :/

Answer (score 16):

If it was me I would introduce new CSS class and use along with unmodified bootstrap row class.

HTML

```
<div class="row extra-bottom-padding" id="a">
   <img>...</img>
<div>
<div class="row" id="b">
   <button>..</button>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.row.extra-bottom-padding{
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Best solution, although the naming should follow bootstrap guidelines: class="row row-gutter"

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

Bootstrap 4 has spacing utilities to handle this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

```
.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

--

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you are using SASS, this is what I normally do.

```
$margins: (xs: 0.5rem, sm: 1rem, md: 1.5rem, lg: 2rem, xl: 2.5rem);

@each $name, $value in $margins {
  .margin-top-#{$name} {
    margin-top: $value;
  }

  .margin-bottom-#{$name} {
    margin-bottom: $value;
  }
}
```

so you can later use `margin-top-xs` for example

Answer (score -1):

Use `<br>` tags

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="row" id="a">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300">
    </div>

    <br><br> <!--insert one, two, or more here-->

    <div class="row" id="b">
      <button>Hello</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote? <br> tags are recommended in bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-addresses

Comment: I think add br is good idea,it is better than add h1 tag.But why not bootstrap give a better solution,they have already define the col-md-offset,why not define rol-md-offset-* again?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the col-md-offset applies to horizontal spacing.  They didn't create anything like that for vertical spacing because it doesn't make sense to constrain vertical spacing in the same way as horizontal spacing.

Comment: <br /> should be used to preserve line breaks in text, where the division of lines are sigificant much like your example, addresses. It should not be used to increase a gap, where instead margin or padding should be used. However notably unfortunately my comment doesn't help with boostrap - but it's generally applicable to CSS / html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: The site Alex KeySmith linked says: "Do not use <br> to increase the gap between lines of text; use the CSS margin property or the <p> element."

Comment: Never format with HTML! HTML is for the DOM **structure**. CSS for the **formattings**.

Comment: Just to clarify, the official Bootstrap documentation does **not** recommend using <br> tags to add space between elements. The documentation uses them to add line breaks to text flow, which is the correct usage.

Comment: @JJJ I agree...I wrote this answer a while ago.  I didn't know this at the time.  Thank you

Answer (score -5):

There's a simply way of doing it.
You define for all the rows, except the first one, the following class with properties:

```
.not-first-row
{
   position: relative;
   top: -20px;
}
```

Then you apply the class to all non-first rows and adjust the negative top value to fit your desired row space. It's easy and works way better. :)
Hope it helped.