# CSS/HTML Seperation line between text

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage About Us section and I have two requirements, two sets of text 'About Us' & 'Clients & feedback'. They need to be side by side and I would like a line separating them. I'm using bootstrap as a framework and I wondered if anyone could tell me how to get the line in place.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section id="section-two" class="section-two">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Placehold</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3>Project Two</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, odit velit cumque vero doloremque repellendus distinctio maiores rem expedita a nam vitae modi quidem similique ducimus! Velit, esse totam tempore.</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows

Comment: Do you mean this -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/66qhh4wd/ ?

Comment: se this   https://jsfiddle.net/4t7e5hgb/

Comment: use `|` this for vertical line

Answer (score 0):

use border-right property on your first column.

```
 border-right: 2px solid black;
```

Comment: This still adds a horizontal line above my second block of text, I want a vertical line between both Columns

Comment: can you kindly prepare a fiddle i can see why there is a horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

add the border like @hars said but only on the first column

```
div.col-lg-6:nth-of-type(1){  border-right: 2px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to add a single line between two columns -

```
.col-lg-6 ~ .col-lg-6 {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1pobwqh/)

*Note:* The above technique will work even if you have more than two columns. [See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r1pobwqh/1/)