# how to give space for every row (CSS issue)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below my output  there is no space for every Row, how to give  space for every row  using Bootstrap CSS? please check the code

```
 <div class="form-group" >

                       <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                       </div>
                   </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>





<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>





<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your html structure is not correct according to bootstrap, however, add `clearfix` to each `.form-group`.

Comment: add class every form-group "clearfix"

Comment: clearfix also not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.form-group > * {
           margin:5px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper markup should be (using your col width as an example):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">Some label</label>
                <input id="input1" placeholder="Type something…" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input2">Some label 2</label>
                <input id="input2" placeholder="Type something…" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As it stands, you don't have any rows defined.