# Bootstrap way to add vertical space between the fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add vertical space between the div's. Is there any bootstrap class I can add here?
Any help?

Below is the snippet from my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4"> Project: </label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.Project, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "Project" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Quantity:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.Quantity, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "Quantity" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no class in the bootstrap toolbox to do this.

So the best way to do it's to add a `top-buffer` class on your row.

```
.top-buffer{
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Here the codepen : https://codepen.io/boydow/pen/ayZeGW

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `<div class="form-group">` as parents like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4"> Project: </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.Project, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "Project" })
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Quantity:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.Quantity, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "Quantity" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class "mt-#" or to your divs to add top margin, where # is a number between 1-5, varying in lengths. If you want to add margin to the top and bottom, you can do "my-#." This class is part of Bootstrap documentation.

```
<div class="your-class mt-3">Your column</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this : `<div class="d-flex align-content-around flex-wrap">`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about gutter. It can used both horizontally and vertiacally in the following way:

```
g-2
gx-2
gy-2
```

Read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/).