# div shifting other divs below

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this page: 
http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/profilestack.html

Trying to put some breadcrumbs together but they give shifting the profile title bar below and I haven't been able to figure out why, anybody can help ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style sheet, add the css rule:

```
#content-container { clear: both; }
```

The problem is that the floating bread crumbs are floating beside your content, you need to explicitly tell your content vertically clear them.

Comment: Why is inline CSS bad form (I have a lot of it) ?

Comment: For those wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add this element right under the "breadcrumbs-container" `div`:

`<div style="clear:both"></div>`

This will clear the floated `div`s above it.

Additionally, you should only have one `div` with the id li-bread. Id's are not meant to be duplicated on the same page. Consider using a class instead of an id.

Comment: It's true what you say about the `ìd`s. You'll want to use `class`, if it appears more than once in the document.

Comment: This will not solve the problem, the content still doesn't clear the breadcrumbs and is still shifted. Plus inline css is very bad form unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Godwin Sorry about the inline CSS; you could alternatively use a class to clear instead. The OP's question explicitly dealt with shifting the divs below; the positioning of the breadcrumbs is a different problem imo.

Comment: Oops, I missed that this is an additional div, so it will solve the problem, it's just an necessary additional element when you can add this styling to the content element itself.