# Font family within a tag

Tags: css

When I have an `a` tag within a `div` whose font-family is specified, the font-family seems to affect only the text within the `div`, but not the text within the `a` tag. Why is that, and how can it be fixed?

```
<div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"> Hello world! <a href="www.google.com"> Click here! </a> </div>
```

Comment: You probably have a rule that overrides the div style. Use firebug to chrome dev tools to inspect that element and see what it shows you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Comment: The attribute `href="www.google.com"` is an odd example, since the value is a relative URL, very different from `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John mentions in comment; you might have some other CSS linked file which is overriding your `font-family`. You can use inherit property inline, as your `div` also has style defined *inline*.

```
<a href="www.google.com" style="font-family: inherit;"> Click here! </a>
```

Comment: Using `inherit` is usually not a good idea, partly because it introduces a normally unnecessary browser dependency: `inherit` is not recognized by IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem described is not caused by the code posted, i.e. the cause is in the part of code that was not disclosed. Generally, setting e.g. `font-family` on an element affects as such only the text directly in the element, not text wrapped in an inner element. However, if there is no CSS rule (in author, user, or browser style sheets in use) for an inner element, *then* an inner element inherits `font-family` from its parent. But in this case there apparently *is* a CSS rule that sets `font-family` on the `a` element.

The fix depends on what other CSS code is used. This does not seem to be a real-life case but just as an exercise, so it’s better to use a different approach, e.g.

```
<div class="foobar"> Hello world! <a href="www.google.com"> Click here! </a> </div>
```

with the following CSS code in a linked external style sheet or within a `style` element on the page:

```
.foobar, .foobar a { font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif }
```

Replace `foobar` by a name that reflects the meaning or role of the element, just to make the code more readable to humans.

However, depending on the other CSS code that sets `font-family` on the `a` element now, you may need to use a more specific selector, or the `!important` specifier, or both.