# Padding right issue

Tags: html, css, menubar

I'm trying to achieve responsive design on a website. The issue I'm having is that I want the navigation menu to fit 100% to the total width, and there is some kind of right padding on the last element ("Equipo") that I want to remove, so the element gets to the border.
How can I achieve that?

HTML:

```
<header class="mainHeader">
    <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuActual">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Obras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Búsqueda Avanzada</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipo</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.mainHeader nav {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
margin: 1% 0;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
float: left;
display: inline;
width: 20%;
}
ul {
padding-left: 0;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
width: 80%;
height: 22px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 0;
text-align: center;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#2e2e2e;
border-left:5px solid #2e2e2e;
}
```

Here's the link of the temporary web file:
http://basevideoarte.com.ar/juan/responsivetemp/index.htm
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try the `last-child` selector, and remove the padding from the last element. `li { padding-right: 10px;} li:last-child {padding-right: 0}`

Comment: Didn't work. I've also put !important after both padding-right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a {
width: 100%;
}

li {
width: 16%;
padding-right: 4%;
}

li:last-child {
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

I didn't look if you had additional margins or padding in there, but if so, adjust to accommodate those and this will solve you issue.

Comment: The problem is not the padding on the li element. There isn't any padding at all.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Here is the problem: The a element is defining your width. Set the a element to 100% width and set the list element to 16% width with a 4% padding-right and a li:last-child with a padding-right of 0px. I'll edit my answer with accurate code.

Comment: @AnthonyWeber that's why I said "kind of", didn't knew what where making that space.

Comment: @DaNoiseMan Yes, but the first version of this answer was just about removing a non-existent padding. Now it's a better solution :)

Comment: @JesseSupamanNichols that worked, but instead of set a 4% padding-right at the css file, I set it on the first four li elements. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! That will work just fine to and and inline-styling is better for earlier browser support.

Answer (score 0):

If you align the last item to the right, the spaces wont be equal anymore. So use `.mainHeader nav ul li{text-align:center;}` to align them equal

Answer (score 0):

You have your `<li>` list items lined up side by side, and the `<a>` links (which have the gray background) are set to 80% width of their parent `<li>`. The links are left-aligned, so you see a gap present on the last one, just like the others, equal to 20% of the list item's width.

**[Edit:]**

Here's a ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDS5L/)*** demonstrating how to space the `<li>`'s out to match the header width, centered for margins on either side. I've illustrated a demo of what's happening in your layout, where the links are only taking up a portion of the list items to simulate space between the links, and I've illustrated how I'd fix that by spacing the list items individually.

Hope this clears it up a little more. Inline styles, as recommended in other answers, are [usually a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css). Best to keep things simple, and flexible.

Comment: You're right, if I put the <a> links to 100% there's no space. Still not having a clue about how to fix it.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to illustrate how I'd fix the issue, avoiding inline styles and pseudo-selectors. Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
.mainHeader nav ul li {
float: left;
width: 16%;
margin-right: 5%;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
width: 100%;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li:last-child {
float: right;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a different perspective.

Using ul/li for nav menus raises issues of "fitting" the ul/lis inside a div. You can "fit" them many different ways. Left padding, right padding, changing the width of the holder div (then centering the div), and I'm sure there are many others.

In [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/2jvXb/) fiddle, I've just changed the padding on the left and it will "center" the ul/li in the div (I've added borders so it's easier to see).

I've only changed this CSS:

```
ul {
padding-left: 23px;
}
```

and added a border around the holder div.

Not better than any other approach, just different.