# how to get particular background div in collection of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have DIV structure like this:

```
   <div id="wire" style="position: absolute">
    <div  style="position: absolute;background:white" ></div>
    <div  style="position: absolute;background:red" ></div>
    <div  style="position: absolute;background:white" ></div>
    <div  style="position: absolute;background:red" ></div>
    <div  style="position: absolute;background:white" ></div>
    </div>
```

I'm able to get all child div's in jquery like this :

```
$("#wire > div")
```

How to get all div's with white background only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#wire > div[style*='background:white']")
```

Comment: Not working this is my results  $("#wire > div").length
36
$("#wire > div[style*='background:white']").length
0

Comment: <div id="wire" style="position: absolute">
<div style="left:05px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D225</div>
<div style="left:105px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D226</div>
<div style="left: 205px; top: 426px; position: absolute; background: white;" class="childdiv">D227</div>
<div style="left:305px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D228</div>
</div> this is my HTML code not working

Comment: @User121212: remove extra space after `:` in background property. it should be `background:white`

Comment: Working great Now ... Can i know how to get other than white ?

Answer (score 1):

Well... first of all you need to remove the inline style. See [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css). So you will have something like this:

CSS:

```
/*CSS*/
.absolute {position:absolute;}
.white {background: white;}
.red {background: red;}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="wire" class="absolute">
   <div class="white absolute"></div>
   <div  class="red absolute"></div>
   <div class="white absolute"></div>
   <div class="red absolute"></div>
   <div class="white absolute"></div>
</div>
```

And then simply do this:

```
$('#wire>div.white')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
$("#wire > div").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.css("position") == "absolute"
    && $this.css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
});
```

Comment: <div id="wire" style="position: absolute">
<div style="left:05px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D225</div>
<div style="left:105px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D226</div>
<div style="left: 205px; top: 426px; position: absolute; background: white;" class="childdiv">D227</div>
<div style="left:305px;top:426px; position: absolute " class="childdiv">D228</div>
</div> this is my HTML code not working

Comment: see updated answer, background checking was wrong, you need to replace color value with it rgb, in this case: white = 255,255,255