# How put a image inside an ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">      
    <li >
        <a href="/GTracker/Account/Login" id="loginLink" style="color:lightgreen">
            Login
            <img src="~/Content/Login-icon-door.png" />
        </a>
    </li>  
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, 
                      htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", style = "color:lightgreen" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

Both go the the right action. But can I use ActionLink helper to also include the image?

[image]

Comment: Url.Action & Url.Content can substitute your ActionLink, then setting CSS property on htmlAttributes to arrange them in proper order. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213704/adding-images-within-html-actionlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to use an ActionLink helper so that you do not have a hard coded path in your view (understandable).

How about this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" id="loginLink" style="color:lightgreen">
    Login
    <img src="~/Content/Login-icon-door.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Url.Action instead of Action.Link

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Login", "Account")%>">Login
            <img src="~/Content/Login-icon-door.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Url.Action to define hyperlink and Url.Content to define image content besides the link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, 
                      htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", style = "color:lightgreen" })
```

has changed to

```
<a id="loginLink" href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account") style="color:lightgreen">Log in 
<img alt="Log in" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Login-icon-door.png")"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some ways you can achieve this is via CSS and Replace.

**HTML Replace with CSS**

With this, you can put in the text + the [replaceable prop] under the text param of the ActionLink. With this, the user does not have to add specific width to for the text.

The image `width` and `height` can also be specified directly instead of adding it in the CSS class. If the image used is already optimized in size, then we don't need to add it anymore. `Position: absolute` is added so the text and image will be aligned properly.

```
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Login [img]", "Index", "Home").ToHtmlString().Replace("[img]", "<img src='../Content/images/LogIn.png' class='imgLink' />"))

    .imgLink {
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

**CSS**

For this, the image is added as the background, so the text width is needed to be specified. The position of the image is set as `center right`.

Sample generated link with image based on the code below:

[image: Sample]

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Login" , "Index" , "Home" , new { @class="imgLinkButton" } )

.imgLinkButton{
    background: url('img.png') no-repeat center right;
    display:block;
    background-size: 20px 20px; 
    height:20px; 
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: You mean `Replace` **OR** `CSS`, those are two different solutions, isnt? For `CSS` Do I need make calculations so image appear on the right of `"Login"` or is automatic?

Comment: I already put it center right for the position. And yes, you can specify the position of the image via CSS

Comment: I mean the bg size is `20x20` I guess that is image size? But your width is 50px so I guess that is for `LOGIN` text? So do I have to calculate the size  if I change text?

Comment: The bg-size is for the image, the width is for the width of the ActionLink. It depends on the length of the text that you put in the ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Url.Action instead.
Here's the cleanest way you can do it:

```
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="~/Assets/Img/myImg.png"/>  </a></li>
```