# Cakephp has many functions that return their options in the correct format. What advantages do they offer over writing the output yourself?

Tags: php, cakephp

This might just be a styling choice, but in case I have misunderstood something fundamental about cakePHP (or possibly all PHP frameworks) I will ask. Cakephp has many functions that take arrays of options and return them in the correct format. One example is HtmlHelper's [style()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-HtmlHelper.html#634-663) function which works like so:

```
echo $this->Html->style(array('margin' => '10px', 'padding' => '10px'), true);

// creates
'margin:10px;padding:10px;'
```

When creating views should stick to these provided functions, or just write the HTML. It seems clearer and more concise to write the markup, but am I then missing out on some of the functionally gifted by the framework.

Comment: Would you mind to provide me a list of the "many" functions you think that are never needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the helpers when you really need them and they spare you from writing lots of HTML. By the way, I haven't used the style method in 8 years.

And *don't* write inline CSS or JS at all, no matter how you generate it:

- [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can assure you I'd never write inline CSS. I referred to the style method only as simple helper function that appeared to not make things any easier. Cheers.

Comment: I think the reason for the style() method is that you can build custom helpers that use an array instead of a string for styles. The advantage here is that you can have a set of defaults and merge or override the passed options as needed. However, I never used it. Would you mind to provide me a list of the "many" functions you think that are never needed?