# How can I implement this with CSS3?

Tags: css

CSS experts can you help me to implement a css file that gives me this design.

[image]

Comment: Better you use bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something, that can help. http://jsfiddle.net/mf36nLrt/

```css
.photo, .div3{
    width: 75px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    float: left;
}

.div1, .div2, .hr, .div4 {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 85px); /* Here 85 is the width of PHOTO + margin + border */
    margin-left: 5px; /*Adjust this value for the space between photo and DIV#1 */
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    height: 50px;
}

.hr{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 0px;
}

.div2{
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 30px;
}

.div3{
    margin-top: 5px;    
}

.div4{
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="hr"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div class="div4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either give more specifications, or here it is:

```css
  .left {
    max-width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .right {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="left">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:5px;">Photo</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black; ">Div 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:5px;">Div 1</div>
    <hr>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">Div 2</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline styling - ***really***?

Comment: What do you have against it?

Comment: [Here's just a few reasons...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) but wait, [there seems to be a few more reasons here...](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/). Hang on, [I can do this too](http://bit.ly/1xy9ZAW)

Comment: Not a single out points out the bad thing about what I did. The question was to show something that resembles his question. I did. What had to be in a css file was put there, the margin and borders are not even needed in the file as I am sure they will be removed.