# HTML/CSS display inline not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image and a h1 element on the same line. I have looked this up and tried to use `display:inline;` for both the parent div element as well as both of the elements.

This is what I have so far

```
<div style="display:inline;">
    <a class="blur" href="#"><img style="margin-top:6px;display:inline;margin-left:1320px;" src="images/gmail.png"></a>
    <h1 style="margin-top:6px;display:inline;margin-left:1220px;font-size:20px;color:white;font-style:italic;">Mail Us</h1>
</div>
```

This displays the image on the line I want, but the h1 element under it.

What I want to accomplish is both of these elements on the same line.

Comment: I'm not sure how big your intended display size is, but you have a `margin-left` of 1320px, I assume there's not going to be much room left for the H1 tag next to it. Without really knowing what you're trying to do, I think you may be better off using `float: right`. [Float article](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: you should be applying the `display: inline` style to the <a> tag not the <img> tag

Comment: my bad the <a> element will display inline by default so just remove it from the <img> tag.

Comment: To prevent the wrapping, add `white-space: nowrap` to the main `div`.  But doing so will put your `h1` tag 1220px to the right of the `img`, which *may* not be what you're going for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use `display:inline-block` for each element (not the parent). Fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lupjuby6/

And please, [do not use CSS inline!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) This is very bad to your HTML, besides making the code more complicated to analyze, and a lot of other bad things.

Comment: What exactly is the dfferent between display:inline and inline-block if CSS inline is bad? EDIT: The elements are still not on the same line.

Comment: `inline-block` solves the problem only because you also removed the left margins.  Restoring them restores the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/bb54c962/

Comment: you do not need to set `display: inline-block` on the <img>, it is a child element of the <a> which displays inline by default

Comment: @JarFile when Rafael says "do not use CSS inline" it is not referring to the block vs **inline** vs inline-block display property; it is referring to including all of your CSS as part of a `style="prop:value; prop:value;"` on an element. Don't do _that_. Read the link Rafael provided. Put your styles in a separate `.css` stylesheet file, and use classes and ids as necessary. It _does_ also look like you are using an `<h1>` simply to make the text big, you're _not_ using it because it is a top level header.

Answer (score -2):

h elements ( `<h1>` , `<h2>` , `<h3>` , etc. )  take up an entire line,  that's just the way they're meant to work.  It is going to be a lot more work  to put another element on the same line,  instead you should try using an `<a>` or `<p>` and style it to look just like the `<h1>` did .

When you make this change just set both elements to

```
display: inline-block;
```