# Make text smaller with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to emulate this image using HTML and CSS. It will be something that will be displayed below the avatar on a message board.

[image: stats]

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/220/

```
table.avatarStats {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

<table class="avatarStats" width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="purple">RECENT WR<br /><strong>61%</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="teal">OVERALL<br /><strong>55%</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="purple">RECENT WN8<br /><strong>2469</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="teal">OVERALL<br /><strong>1737</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The main problem I'm having is decreasing the size of the text above the numbers. Nothing I've tried is making the text smaller.

Also, is there a better way of bolding the numbers?

Comment: This *may* be an issue with your browser not working with JSFiddle correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```css
table.avatarStats {
 border-spacing: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
td small{
    font-size:7pt;
    font-weight:bold;
}
td strong{
    
    font-size:18pt; 
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="avatarStats" width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="purple"><small>RECENT WR</small><br /><strong>61%</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="teal"><small>OVERALL</small><br /><strong>55%</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="purple"><small>RECENT WN8</small><br /><strong>2469</strong></td>
      <td bgcolor="teal"><dev font-size: 10pt;><small>OVERALL</small><br /><strong>1737</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to make the font smaller.

```
font-size: 10pt;
```

Just replace 10pt with whatever size you want to use.

I would use a CSS class like:

```
.small {
   font-size: 10pt;   
}
```

and add

```
class="small"
```

to the text you want to be small

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't do anything. I've also tried font-size: 10px; and font-size: 40%; and font size="8"

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```css
table.avatarStats {
 border-spacing: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.cap{
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
td{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:22px
}
```

```html
<table class="avatarStats" width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="purple"><span class="cap">RECENT WR</span><br /><strong>61%</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="teal"><span class="cap">OVERALL</span><br /><strong>55%</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td bgcolor="purple"><span class="cap">RECENT WN8</span><br /><strong>2469</strong></td>
      <td bgcolor="teal"><span class="cap">OVERALL</span><br /><strong>1737</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Adjust the font-size accordingly as needed***

Answer (score 1):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/fd9x06jq/

```
table.avatarStats tr td strong{
  font-size:9pt;    
  font-weight:bold;
  color:black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd advise some changes to your markup, add this to you CSS:

```
table tr td:last-child{
    font-size: 8pt;   
}
```

**EDIT:**

My first code was off. Now it's correct. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/224/)

Comment: what kind of changes?

Comment: to your markup? you control your styles using properties such as bgcolor and whatnot. I'd keep all styles within the same (css) file

Comment: but anyways, if you dont want to change anything, the selector I build does what you need

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/70gtky65/1/

```
<table class="avatarStats">
  <tr>
    <td>RECENT WR<br/><span>61%</span></td>
    <td>OVERALL<br/><span>55%</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>RECENT WN8<br/><span>2469</span></td>
      <td>OVERALL<br/><span>1737</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
    table.avatarStats {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 108px;
    }

    table.avatarStats td {
        font-size: 7px;
        width: 50px;
        padding: 2px;
    }

    table.avatarStats td span {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    table tr td:first-child {
        background-color: #7842B3;
    }

    table tr td:last-child {
        background-color: #459ABD;
    }
</style>
```

You should try to avoid inline CSS and [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

Comment: I have to use it inline for this but the colors will be changed to a php variable.

Comment: Updated the code, use a tag <style>, and replace the color values by your PHP variable, that way you will be able to reuse that style with retyping all this variable on multiple places. <style> tag should go inside the <head> section of your page