# Scrambled elements when resizing

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<p style="margin-left:1250px; margin-top:70px;"><a href="">Go to the main website</a></p>
```

css:

```
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Whenever i re-size the browser's window "Go to the main website" is getting scrambled.
Any help?

Comment: Get rid of that inline style.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm new in web development, can you be more specific which element?

Comment: If you can't recognize an inline style, you need to Google it.

Comment: ok i did, but how can i keep the element in the same position, using the inline style :style="margin-left:1250px; margin-top:70px;"

Comment: i named the <P> --><p1> and i gave it the attr: style="margin-left:1250px; margin-top:70px;" in CSS but it diidn't take the original position top-right

Comment: Couple things: [Inline styles are bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css).  You should make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

Css

```
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

html {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.custom-class {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top:70px;
}
```

Html

```
<p class="custom-class"><a href="">Go to the main website</a></p>
```

Comment: you're a life saver!! just one question how can i move the sentence just a bit to the left

Comment: Just add a `margin-right: 20px;` to the custom class in css.

Comment: man thank you a lot... Can we by any chance open a chat i have just one more question

Comment: Thank you, but how to open a private chat in SO?

Comment: I usually wait for the chat initiation process above the comment section