# Javascript - Multi-Usage of General Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a example of a situation here, I want to change the color of a `div` when clicked. Do I have to have two different functions, one for each `div`? What if the functions that I wanted to apply to the `div` was very complex? What if I had hundereds of the `div`? Can I make a *general* function, that can be applied for every `div`? By this I do not mean for example `document.getElementsByClassName(" ... ")`, I want to for example change the color of the separately.

To be clear, how can I apply the *same* function to different objects? Something like `document.getElementThatIsClicked(" ... " )` Thank you.

```js
function changeColor1() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "#21a9c9";
}
function changeColor2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "#21a9c9";  
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onClick="changeColor1()" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left: 10px; width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:#000000;"></div>
                      
<div id="div2" onClick="changeColor2()" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 220px; width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:#000000;"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Can you restate the question?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Sorry for being unclear, better now? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that accepts the element you want to change the color and make the function change the background color for that element

```js
 function changeColor(elem) {
   elem.style.backgroundColor = "#21a9c9"
 }
```

```html
<div id="div1" onClick="changeColor(this)" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left: 10px; width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:#000000;"></div>

<div id="div2" onClick="changeColor(this)" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 220px; width:200px; height: 200px; background-color:#000000;"></div>
```

Comment: I was just typing the exact same thing ;)

Comment: Ok, so I use `function(this)` in the `onClick` and `elem` in the function declaration? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't suggest HTML attribute  handlers

Comment: @JakeTheSnake, Yes, when do an inline function call (which is calling the javascript function inside onclick attribute in the html tag), you can pass 'this' keyword as a parameter to be able to access the element which had the event. then inside the function you will have access to that element and would be able to modify it or do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 1):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828729/227299 but:

- Avoids setting handlers using  inline HTML attributes in favor of unobtrusively setting handlers from JavaScript itself. See [onclick="" vs event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941483/onclick-vs-event-handler)
- Avoid setting CSS attributes from HTML attributes. See [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

```js
function changeColor(elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#21a9c9"
}


var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    changeColor(this);
  });
}
```

```css
#div1,#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```