# How can i position text on my HTML page without using CSS ?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner to HTML and I'm trying to position text on my HTML page i am unsure if CSS is needed to position text on a page.

Comment: you do need CSS to position the elements on the page

Answer (score 2):

CSS is absolutely how you position and style any HTML elements. You can use simple tags, like `<b>` or `<i>`, for minor formatting. Unless you're only building a [motherfucking website](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/), you'll want to use CSS. If you run into problems, post specific issues in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

great that you are diving into html !

Because this seems like a "basic" question and you've pointed out you are a beginner I'm just going to recommend some resources to learn more:

https://www.codecademy.com/ is a great source for learning code and it's free.
They have an html/css course [right here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web)

some others which offer basic html/css courses (not free):
https://www.codeschool.com/
https://teamtreehouse.com/

Have fun learning!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
<b style="margin: auto; width: 13px; color: yellow; background-color: red;>Some text</b>
```

this is a very basic part of html :) good luck learning html and have fun coding :)

Comment: As I say in another comment below, inline CSS should be used sparsely, if at all. Use separate .css files and ```<link>``` them to your HTML document.

Comment: [More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) [thorough](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/when-is-inline-css-a-good-idea) [arguments](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) [against](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) [inline](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138538/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-inline-styling-with-generated-code) [CSS](http://www.sitekickr.com/blog/reasons-avoid-inline-css-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

You do need CSS, however you can use styles in your HTML tags, but this should be very limited. For example

```
<div style="background-color: black; color: grey; margin: auto;">Some text</div>
```

or if you don't want to have a separate CSS file, you can use CSS in HTML like this:

Something

```
<style>
div {
background-color: black;
color: grey;
margin: auto;
}
```

In both cases you are using CSS only they are in your HTML file.

I STRONGLY encourage you  to start learning CSS, as that is something you will need.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using inline CSS. For one thing, priority is given to styles declared inline, which makes it trickier to create classes and/or style your elements from a stylesheet. For another thing, it's better organizationally to keep your CSS in separate file(s) and attach it to your HTML document with a ```<link>``` tag; this will keep things organized as your project grows.

Comment: I strongly agree, I'm only giving the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content in `<center>` tags, so it looks like this: `<center>..Content..</center>`