# Why is changing CSS properties by using JavaScript considered a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, css

Some people state that changing the CSS via the style object is a bad practice.

For example doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById('message').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

Instead one should add / remove classes for influencing the layout.

Unfortunately nobody becomes precise **why** it is bad to use the style-object.

Therefore my question here:

Can someone explain why one shall avoid this technique?

Comment: It is personal opinion and using classes is normally better since you know where the styles are at. Sometimes you will see someone setting 10 style properties in a row and that is just a bad idea.

Comment: With the above, you are going to add inline styles. And why inline styles are bad, here is a good reasoning - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Comment: because it mixes program logic with presentation