# footer not staying at bottom of page

Tags: css, footer

I realise this question has been asked before but I have tried

```
footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

html, body {
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

I have also tried a CSS tricks method https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

None of these options have worked for me (or at least not for very-large screen). What else can I try? Thanks

Comment: What about `position:relative;`?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a [jsfiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net), as your code should be fine as demoed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0aL7b4zo/)

Comment: d00d, use flexbox: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

html, body {
min-height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: the HTML tag is relative by default (the code provided in the question *should* work).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing various styles that are essential to applying a 'sticky footer'. This is how i've always done it

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/zmbh0v4z/

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
  background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @jbutler483 His code will not work well in all cases. It is simply positioned absolute, nothing else. As soon as enough content is added to the page to make it scroll the footer will be overlayed with content - in theory.

Comment: Which, in theory, should work. I'm not saying anything about overlaying content, as OP has not said anything about what's actually wrong with the code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

HTML

```
<section class="footer id="footer">
Content
</section>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
background-color: #63C0B8;
color: #1e1e1e;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

That hashtag is **IMPORTANT**

Also note that the footer will stay on the bottom ... but you need to put content above it first.

Comment: You are making a lot of presumptions here, especially as it is more than likely OP is using a `footer` element, and hence is valid a CSS selector.

Comment: The element being used is a footer, it's not an id.

Comment: Above answer is edited to add HTML code. Use the footer as an element instead of the footer being an actual <footer> tag. It works for me.

Comment: Why would you use a `section` tag if a `footer` tag is already available? (small point though, you need to close your class definition in your HTML to make it valid)

Comment: Because that's the only method that worked for me, since all of my CSS is inline in my AMP HTML pages.

Comment: @RobertDewitt inline CSS is a very bad practise to get into, you should always aim to have that placed externally. It is my understanding caching can then take place to increase performance.

Comment: Per AMP standards, I think that's how it was outlined to be used. But I don't have issues with it, although I understand the practice is rather bad.

Comment: [That. Sounds. Horrible. And here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)