# Centering a Table in xHTML

Tags: xhtml, html-table, alignment

I need to center an entire table in xHTML.  The tags that work in HTML to do so do not necessarily work in xHTML, but the way to do it is not obvious (to me).

Works in HTML:

```
<div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:90%;">
```

Not working in xHTML:

```
<div>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="align:center;border-collapse:collapse; width:90%;">
```

Using text-align:center instead changes the alignment of text within cells, rather than the alignment of the entire table on the page.

What is the correct method to center align a table in xHTML.

Comment: I think you're better off using the margins to center it.  like, "margin:0px auto".  That works WAY better.

Comment: If you're going to use CSS anyway, you should also convert `border`, `cellpadding` and `cellspacing`. By the way, `align` isn't a CSS property; you meant `text-align`. That won't work though; see durbnpoisn's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use margins in the style attribute:

```
<table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
```

Comment: How is this better than durbnpoisn's answer?

Comment: Haha...  Yeah, I got burned on that one.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Posting as answer.
I think you're better off using the margins to center it. like:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

That works WAY better.   Hope that helps!

Comment: If in fact the need is to center a table in an XHTML page, with emphasis on the "X", then this may be the better answer because it illustrates the CSS that would be used to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css#answer-2612494, et alia.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you're using **CSS** to change adjective/styling whereas (X)HTML concentrates on noun constructs (headers, images, paragraphs, etc). XHTML `table` is a noun, CSS `margin` and `text-align` are adjectives used to describe those nouns.

Also it's simpler to use a block/inline catch-all class:

```
.center {margin: auto; text-align: center;}
```