# How to change the behavior of the following css button?

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I am working in the following small page, I have two buttons, one to hide a textarea and the other to show it, in fact they work well however I would like to color the buttom called: Hide in green, in order to do it I tried:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="hide()"  background-color= "green"; ><span>Hide</span></button>
</div>
```

but It doesn't affect the behavior of my button, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to fix the problem, I created the following jsfiddle file to show the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/12bkgd4q/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `background-color= "green";` outside style attribute, you need to put it inside style attribute

```
<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:green" onclick="hide()";><span>Hide</span></button>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/12bkgd4q/11/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` is a style property, and the colour `green` is the property-value of that style property; as they're style properties they should be in the `style` attribute along with the other style(s):

```
<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle; background-color: green;" onclick="hide()"><span>Hide</span></button>
```

What you may have been trying to use, but mis-remembering, is the old (now obsolete) `bgcolor` attribute, which would also set the background-color of an element.

Answer (score 1):

flip around background color and the JavaScript call, like this:

```
style="vertical-align:middle; background-color:green;" onclick="hide();"
```

Answer (score 1):

**OBSERVATIONS:**

Declaring inline-style css works, but the best approach is to use external css to separate style from content as well as using [unobstrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to bind events.

---

**SOLUTION:**

1. Change misspelling in "buttom2" to "button2".
2. Remove inline-styles. (Remove style attribute from buttons tag). Add the desired css properties in your external CSS file.
3. Remove onclick event from your button tag and add identifiers to your buttons so that you can later bind event listeners with jQuery in a separate JS file.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
var sTextO = $("#texto");

$("#triggerBtn1").on("click", function() {
  sTextO.show();
});

$("#triggerBtn2").on("click", function() {
  sTextO.hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#out1 {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 25px solid navy;
  margin: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px red;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 28px;
}
.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.button2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="70" rows="15" id="texto"></textarea>
<div id="out1"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="triggerBtn1" class="button button1"><span>Show</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="triggerBtn2" class="button button2"><span>Hide</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

---

**MORE INFO:**

*JS*: [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

*CSS*: [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

Answer (score 0):

Add this into css

```
.button2 {
  background: green;
}
```

And there is a typo here -

```
<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="hide()" background-color="green" ;><span>Hide</span></button>
```

Change the classname from "buttom2" to "button2"

Answer (score 0):

The color should be set in the style attribute of the button tag.

```
<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle; background-color:green" onclick="hide()">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhe768Ld/

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with " " , basically style tag ended just after vertical-align, so it does not recognize the background-color. Include them inside " ".

Hope this would solve your issue:

`<button class="button buttom2" style="vertical-align:middle; background-color:green" onclick="hide()"><span>Hide</span></button>`