# how to get Specific font style for all the posts in blogger

Tags: post, blogs, blogger, blogspot, blogger-dynamic-views

1 http://kumarunlock.blogspot.com/2017/06/get-helmet-rs9-only-unlocked.html
2 https://kumarunlock.blogspot.in/2015/06/swiggy-app-get-rs100-off-on-your-first.html

please check both the links they contains different font styles. I want the font style which is in link 1 to all the old post as well as the upcoming new posts.
Thank you.

Comment: I want to go to space...

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the same font style for all your Blogger blog posts, replace `.post-body` styles with this following styles.

```
.post-body {
    background-color: white;
    color: #444444;
    font-family: "arial" , "tahoma" , "helvetica" , "freesans" , sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 26px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and remove all the inline css styles from your blog posts span elements.

Comment: thanks for helping.how to remove all the inline css styles from blog posts span elements.

Comment: Go to the Posts section of your blog. Now click Edit to open the post in blogger post editor. Now hit the HTML button. There you will see the html codes of that blog post.`<span style="background-color: white; font-family: "arial" , "tahoma" , "helvetica" , "freesans" , sans-serif;">` remove `style="background-color: white; font-family: "arial" , "tahoma" , ]ikhelvetica" , "freesans" , sans-serif;"` now the code should be `<span>` only.. do this for the rest of the span elements.

Comment: Never use this inline css styles as this effects the page load time. If you want to add css styles then put those css styles just above the `</style>` or `]]></b:skin>` tag of your blog. [What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)