# Is it possible to add css to specific section of a page?

Tags: css, addition

hi I want to add css in title sections in my page

I have a different sections in 1 page

but I want to change in each section fonts and color of title text

but not sure about how to do that

[image]

Comment: Can you not add a class per section you want to change and then write custom rules for each of those CSS classes?

Answer (score 3):

Give each section a class, and then apply the stylings to the children of that class. For example:

```css
.section-1 h2{
  color:#fff;
}
.section-1{
  background-color:orange;
}
.section-1 p{
  color:blue;
}
.section-2 h2{
  color:#fff;
}
.section-2{
  background-color:peachpuff;
}
.section-2 p{
  color:black;
}
.section-3 h2{
  color:#fff;
}
.section-3{
  background-color:pink;
}
.section-3 p{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="section-1">
   <h2>Section 1</h2>
   <p>Filler paragraph text</p>
</div>
<div class="section-2">
   <h2>Section 2</h2>
   <p>Filler paragraph text</p>
</div>

<div class="section-3">
   <h2>Section 3</h2>
   <p>Filler paragraph text</p>
</div>

<div class="section-4">
   <h2>Section 4</h2>
   <p>Filler paragraph text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make separate css options via Id attribute.

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp. "The id Attribute"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style attribute
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp

```
<h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center">This is a header</h1>
<p style="color:green">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Inline css styles are bad. You should read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612483/5894241).

Comment: Managing them becomes a nightmare in large applications if you are working with vanilla javascript and html. Thats not the case with however with React Native where you have styles injected per tag and also react components for used in broswers have styles injected instead of having class conflicts like with material-ui.