# Bulma - Button Class forcing Inline

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am new to [bulma](https://bulma.io) but have been trying to make a simple webpage with it.

I have run into a frustrating problem where I believe one of the classes "button is-large" is forcing elements on my page to be inline.

Here is a minimal code demonstration of what is happening:

```
  <div class="column" style="height: 200px">
    <a class="button is-fullwidth" style="height: 100%">
       <p> <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30611-200.png" alt=""> </p>
       <p class="title">Print Release</p>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The elements in the above code will show up inline.

I want the elements inside of the "a tag" to stack on top of one another. When the "a tag" has the class "button is-fullwidth" it forces the two elements to be inline; whereas if this class is removed they will end up on top of one another no issues.

Here is a [full jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etk7ctu2/) demonstrating different approaches I have taken to resolve my issue. I have tried three different ways to make these elements appear on new lines but to no avail.

Is this just an inherent property of the "button ..." class? Can I keep the button class while also maintaining new lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `button` is styled using flexbox. The property `display: flex` makes its contents appear 'inline'. You can learn more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

There are several ways to get the layout you want, here is one approach:

1. Add the `.is-block` modifier to `a.button` - This will override the `display` property, and ensure that block elements will stack. In your example, `p` is a block element, and `img` is an `inline` element. (Alternatively, you could correct this in CSS by adding `flex-direction: column` to your button.)
2. Instead of adjusting the height of `.column` using inline CSS, you could create a new modifier class that can be added to columns when you need a fixed height. I have added `is-fixed-height` and `height-200` to the `.column` and used some custom CSS to define these.
3. Bulma gives `.button` a `height` of `2.25em`. You need to override this with `100%`. Again, you could create a modifier class and add it to the button (something like `is-height-100`), or simply target the button you want with CSS. Both options are preferable than using inline CSS.
4. The images you are using are too big to allow the text to fit in below the button. Instead of using `height: 200px` on the column, use `min-height`. If you must use a `height` of `200px`, you will need to make some adjustments to the image. Let me know and I can try help.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/8tx3b0bp/1/)

```css
.is-fixed-height.height-200 {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.is-fixed-height.height-200 .button {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-fixed-height height-200">
        <a class="button is-block is-fullwidth">
          <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30611-200.png" alt="">
          <p class="title">Print Release</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-fixed-height height-200">
        <a class="button is-block is-fullwidth">
          <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30611-200.png" alt="">
          <p class="title">Print Release</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-fixed-height height-200">
        <a class="button is-block  is-fullwidth">
          <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30611-200.png" alt="">
          <p class="title">Print Release</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The fiddle you provided seems to be working for me for now! Just two questions: how did you know button is using flexbox? Why is inline CSS so frowned upon (a link for this answer, as I am assuming it is extensive, is fine)?

Comment: Your second question has been asked before, so I will just link you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a way for me to fit any image (reasonable in size maybe 300px X 300px) into the button?

Comment: @Aball Yes, those dimensions will work with the code. Ideally you would add the `.image` class to the image, and wrap it in its own container. You can take a look at the various Bulma components and how they work with images e.g. Card

Answer (score 0):

You gave the anchor a class of button and full-width

> The class `button` always place content inline

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn is-fullwidth" style="height: 100%">
   <p> <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/30611-200.png" alt=""> </p>
   <p class="title">Print Release</p>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
text-align: center;
}
```

I have changed the `button` class with custom class name `btn` then I gave it a center align with CSS

Comment: Okay that was what I was making sure of. There is no way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Yes but there is an alternative to it

Comment: If you could provide the alternative way of structuring the HTML that would be appreciated. I want to keep the look and feel of the button class but without the inline elements

Comment: You change the `button` class to a custom class name and give it your own CSS style, Okay I will edit my answer to show you