# change h1 in different pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP site, every page have a heading H1 acting as a title, right that code change the that heading like this, if the page is services post that if not post the title of tha page, but I want to post a different title that the name of the page.

Here is my code:

```
    <h1 style="background: #000;
     color:#FFF;
     margin-bottom:10px;
     padding:8px 12px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 16px;">

     <?php if (is_page('services')) {
      ?>SERVICES<?php 
       } else { 
        the_title();
       }
      ?>

</h1>
```

Comment: Have you ever used PHP before?

Comment: Not really @TricksfortheWeb

Comment: OK, so go learn about PHP before you try messing around with WP code.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here to even figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So many things to address:

1. [Don't use inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612494/870729).  That is bad form.  Assign a CSS class, and add the CSS to your stylesheet.
2. [Format your code](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/).  Never-ending blocks of code are impossible to read, diagnose, and troubleshoot.
3. Doing it this way is going to lead to a big mess of conditional if statements.  [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) is only going to handle one override for you at a time, AND it's brittle - if the page slug / title changes, this function will no longer pick it up.  I'd strongly recommend getting and using something like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and allow setting the "Display Title" that way.  It'd be much easier to code, maintain, etc.

Lastly - using what little you've given us, here is your code restructured into a much more readable, usable, and functioning solution:

```
<?php
// Load the title into a variable for simpler manipulation / logic
$title = get_the_title();
// If the page is the 'services' slug page, set the title
if ( is_page('services') ) {
   $title = 'Services';
}

// other conditions can go here, if you like
if ( is_page('contact' ) {
   $title = 'Contact Us';
}
?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @cale_b if oe on my pages is in a sub tree like this www.somethin.com/services/somethingelse should I use the is page fucnction like this ` if ( is_page ('services/somethingelse')` or just the name of that page? thank you so much

Comment: Just the name of the page.  _Better_ would be the ID of the page, eg `is_page(21)`....

Comment: Im getting a error on this line if ( is_page('mock-trial' )

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question.  If my answer helped you, then great!  If you're trying to add new code, and having a hard time, then you need to ask a new question.  (Also, if my answer helped, please consider clicking the "upvote" button - the big arrow to the left, just above the number)