# How can I change the height of an iframe for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries, viewport

I have a form that is an iframe. 
The code is below with a # for what the iframe is.
On desktop I need the frame to be 292px in height to match the design.
On tablet it needs to have height="180"
On mobile height="292"
I have tried making the height 100% and changing the size of the  holding the iframe but the iframe is too short and cuts off the bottom of the form
Can I do adjust the height of an iframe for different viewports?

```
<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="292" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is `#` on the same domain as the page the `<iframe>` is on? What's the height of the `<form>` within the `<iframe>`?

Comment: Brilliant! @zer00ne

Comment: That's a first. No one has ever derived a solution from just my inquiries before, good for you 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called **responsive.css** and add it to your styles. It's good practice to add this file after other css files as you want these rules to take priority over your other css rules.

This would be the content of your responsive.css

```
/* Style for Extra Large Screen */
@media (max-width:1199px) {
    iframe {
        height: 292px;
    }
}

/* Style for Large Screen */
@media (max-width:991px) {
    iframe {
        height: 292px;
    }
}

/* Style for Medium Screen */
@media (max-width:767px) {
    iframe {
        height: 180px;
    }
}

/* Style for Small Screen */
@media (max-width:575px) {
    iframe {
        height: /* whatever height you want for mobile */
    }
}
```

Depending on your screen size, the correct section of responsive.css will be used in your website. For example, if you are on mobile, then `@media (max-width:575px)` will be selected. Just put your required height in here.

Comment: This works great thank you for your detailed explanation. I would also like to add that this will only work if the iframe doesn't have a height=" " in the html as this overrides styles from the responsive.css stylesheet

Comment: Thanks Jessica,that's true. Though it is not a good practice to use inline css at the first place: see here  https://speckyboy.com/good-bad-css-practices/ or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css