# How to remove a block for <xl size bootstrap 4

Tags: html

what I should write to hide/remove this block and create a space for < xl devices. http://prntscr.com/iw1fm7 As you see on screenshot,it works good for > 1200px,and I want to remove the central part for < 1200px and create a space for right block https://prnt.sc/iw1evv I mean this.What I should write?

Comment: see this if you want to know how to work with responsive bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419074/how-can-i-change-the-height-of-an-iframe-for-different-screen-sizes/49419333#49419333

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element in bootstrap 4 you may do not have to write custom css but just use the responsive utility classes:

```
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">
   I'm only visible for XL displays and hidden for everything below XL
</div>
```

This will hide the block for all but display it as block in xl and above.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/JIpnQyJDBD2u1D3nRiRU?p=preview

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/