# How to remove something in page in a certain width?

Tags: html, css

How to remove something in page in a certain width, for example, I have an image it ruined my site when you open the site in a phone so I want to remove it in phone size and thanks for reading:

[image]

Comment: look into media queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide div element when screen size is smaller than a specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476267/hide-div-element-when-screen-size-is-smaller-than-a-specific-size)

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419074/how-can-i-change-the-height-of-an-iframe-for-different-screen-sizes/49419333#49419333) might help, you can create different `@media` rules for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [@media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) in conjunction with max-width!

Your CSS might look like this:

```
@media (max-width:575px) {
    .remove-me {
        display: none;
    }
}
```