# How can I make the lines of words closer together, also my boarder does not go across all the way

Tags: css, html

*updated question from previous one*

How can I make the lines of words closer together? also my boarder does not go across all the way
Another update--> I figured out the line spacing issue just can't figure out the boarder
//css

```
   .headerC {
   background: #89cff0;
   font: 36pt/40pt courier;color: white; 
   font-variant: small-caps; 
   border: thick dashed hotpink;

}
```

//html

```
<div class="headerC">
                <h1 align="center" >Contact</h1>
                <h4 align="center"> <a href="tel:203-831-9722" class="link">203-831-9722</a></h4>
                <h5 align="center" >234 East Ave 06855</h5>
                <h6 align="center" >Norwalk, CT</h6>

        </div>
```

Comment: So put he border style on the containing `<div>` instead.

Comment: you try putting a border on `.header` ...?

Comment: You should know that using inline `style` attributes like this is strongly discouraged today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css

Comment: ok im a beginner

Comment: @MelissaChillington I realize, I meant that to be helpful, sorry if it came across otherwise. We were all beginners once.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplified version of code using external css and border on outer div:

HTML

```
 <div class="header">
     <h1 align="center" >Contact</h1>
     <h4 align="center"> <a href="tel:203-831-9722" class="link">203-831-9722</a></h4>
     <h4 align="center" >234 East Ave 06855</h4>
     <h4 align="center" >Norwalk, CT</h4>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  background: #00080;
  font: 36pt/40pt courier; 
  font-variant: small-caps; 
  border: thick dashed hotpink;
}
.link {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

erase the `border`style from the `h1` and `h4`elements and apply it to the container `div`

(plus you might want to use classes to be able to address HTML elements and put all CSS into an external stylesheet, which defines these classes)

Comment: yea I have an external css but I did inline because I thought it would be easier