# How to center <ion-item-divider> text in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How can text be horizontally centered within a `<ion-item-divider>` element in Ionic 4?

I can't find anything in the Ionic 4 [docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/) on centering html component text. In the Ionic 3 docs, I found the `text-center` attribute utility as shown below and documented [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/#text-alignment), but it doesn't work.

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      Hello, I am left aligned
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-divider text-center>
      PLEASE CENTER ME!
    </ion-item-divider>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I also tried adding `style="text-align: center;"` to the `<ion-item-divider>` element, but that did nothing as well.

Comment: might be a bug since Ionic 4 is early beta

Comment: Ionic 4 keeps its css utilities. See the docs here:
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Comment: @Javier Sadly, it does not seem to be the case..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
  <ion-item-divider>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">PLEASE CENTER ME!!</div>
  </ion-item-divider>
```

ugly :(

Answer (score 3):

You can create a css class and call it center. I used the global variables.scss in the directory theme:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

then you can do something like this:

```
<ion-label>
    <p class="center">Some text</p>
</ion-label>
```

Please Don't use inline styles.. 
[What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic 4 it looks like you're supposed to set the text-center on the ion-label, try:

`<ion-item-divider>
    <ion-label text-center>PLEASE CENTER ME!!</ion-label>
 </ion-item-divider>`

Comment: You need to put width: 100% in the ion-label: 

...
<ion-label text-center style="width: 100%;">PLEASE CENTER ME!!</ion-label>
...

Comment: Not anymore apparently, it is working fine with v4.1

Answer (score 0):

this has been replaced with ion-text-center

```
<ion-item-divider class="ion-text-center">
  PLEASE CENTER ME!
</ion-item-divider>
```