# Eliminate the horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem while adding an image to my project site.

So, when I use the element tag name only like 'img' then there is no horizontal  scroll but when i use that image using a class selector like '.class img', then the horizontal scroll appears.
Please help me I have never see a problem like this...

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    
    
}

.about {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.home {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.first-img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="about" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
        <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="first-img">
        <img class="first" src="hamburger.jpg" />
    </div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Maybe is the original size of the image... set a `max-width`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  May I point out that this questions was tagged with "web", which speficially reads "Do not use this tag".  I'm editing to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing this problem because width of the image will be greater than the viewport width to fix the horizontal scroll do the following:

```
.first {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto
}
```

Comment: But can you tell me the reason when I'm using first-img it's not working... Why??? I need to know the reason

Comment: @user8490455 when you applied width: 100% on .first-img means you applied on the div and as image size is larger than viewport width it overflowed.

Comment: May I suggest two edits to this: 1. adding `max-width: 100%;` is also a good idea, and 2. if you're going to set width to 100%, then it's important to add `height: auto;`

Comment: @cale_b thanks yes it's good to set max-width 100% so if any case in the future image is smaller than device width it's resolution will not be disturbed on stretching beyond its width. I am updating my post to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your class, also, I believe your HTML class needs to be first-img, not just "first"

```
 .first-img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
  }
```

"overflow-x" hides the horizontal, "overflow-y" hides the vertical

Comment: But by using overflow the problem is not going to solve it's just hide that scroll and the image will get cut off.

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You Dont Need to add class for just width of image Simply Do this !

```
<img src="hamburger.jpg" width="100%" />
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - but inline styles are [generally a bad pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css).  It is indeed better to add classes that are useful and can be easily updated.