# how to make the borders of a text field scales to fit the size of the text field in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a **CSS/HTML** project and I have a problem with the borders of the text fields. In the browser, the borders are shorter than the text fields.

I tried changing the size of the border to fit the text field and it worked but I tried opening the browser (IE) on a bigger screen and I faced the same problem again.

Here is my code:

```html
<tr>
  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>
    <div style="border:4px #26a570 solid;
               background-color:white; 
      width:37.5%; 
      height:15%">
      <input type="text" name="txtFirst" id="txtFirst" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want the border to scale to the size of the text box in all the browser and screens.

Comment: Instead of the `div`, set border to the `input` field

Comment: this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hey man I added an answer for you. It has the correct way of styling and examples for you to do what you want. Check it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First like @Nimsrules mentioned put your border around the input. 
Second use a viewport. this will make it scaleable. Your viewport has to be in the head. And instead of using % you can use `vw` for the width en `vh` for the height.

**Example**

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<tr>
    <td>First Name
</td>
    <td>
<div > 
    <input type="text" name="txtFirst" id="txtFirst" style="border:4px #26a570
 solid;background-color:white; width:37.5vw; height:15vh"/>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjyut2fx/)

Here you can read more about [viewports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport).

Also I wouldn't recommend inline css. It is better to use a css file. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css) for more information why it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style on the input element,

It does not work because you had `width:37.5%;`set to the parent also.

```html
  <table>
  
  <tr>
    <td>First Name
</td>
    <td>
<div> 
    <input style="width: 200px; border:4px #26a570
 solid;background-color:white; height:15%" type="text" name="txtFirst" id="txtFirst" />
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: it is weird I tried applying your solution and the border disappeared, I don't know why

Comment: As per my understanding , i suggest using position relative in div instead of width

Comment: @W.M well you can clearly see the border in my solution, so you must have some other css overwriting it

Answer (score 0):

You can **set border to the input field** and check it on IE.

If it does not work then try to **break out the border CSS** you have applied, as

> border-color: grey;

and

> border-style:solid;

instead of single tagging, you can try this.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Firstly it is bad to write inline styles because editing can be a pain. You should set a class and write the styles in your CSS file :)

Here's your HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>
      <div> 
          <input class="input-wrapper" type="text" name="FirstName" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's your CSS

```
input.input-wrapper{
  border:5px solid green;
}
```

And here's your INLINE style

```
<input style="border:5px solid green;" type="text" name="FirstName" />
```

Comment: is it possible to make it work using the inline CSS? because the project I'm working on has the HTML and CSS files separately, it is kind of hard to edit both I' haven't tried it before. and I don't want to miss things up.