# Update function to recognize links

Tags: php, regex

I have this function to recognize and convert hashtag, emoji etc

```
function convert_text($str) {
        $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
    //type and links
        $hrefs = [
            '#' => 'hashtag.php?hashtag',
            '@' => 'user.php?user'
        ];

        $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
             return sprintf(
                 '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
                 $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
                 $matches[1], 
                 $matches[0]
             );
        }, $str);

        //$result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", '\u{${1}}', $result);
        $result = preg_replace('/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/', '<span style="font-size:30px;">&#x\\1;</span>', $result);

        return ($result);
    }
```

I would like to make it recognize `http://` and `https://` from text and than convert to:

`<a href="http://link.com">http://link.com</a>` 
how to implement this inside the function?

Comment: What's the point in *converting* emojis? They're characters already.

Comment: the function already recognize  and convert emoji already, I would like to make it reconize and convert links `http` `https`

Comment: I saw that page while I was researching this question.  It does one thing that is required, but that technique needs to be properly integrated into the OP's pre-existing script to provide the OP's desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't go down the rabbit hole about constructing a world-conquering regex pattern to extract all valid urls the world can dream up including unicode while denying urls with valid characters but illogical structures.  (I'll go with [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/2943403) and move on.)

For a regex demo see: https://regex101.com/r/HFCP1Z/1/

Things to note:

- If a url is matched, there is no capture group, so `$m[1]` isn't generated.  If a user/hash tag is matched, the fullstring match and capture group 1 is generated.  If an emoji is matched, the fullstring match is populated, the capture group 1 element is empty (but declared because php generates `$m` as an indexed array -- no gaps), and capture group 2 holds the emoji's parenthetical substring.
- You **need** to be sure that you don't accidentally replace part of a url which contains a qualifying hashtag/usertag substring.  (Currently, the other answers don't consider this vulnerability.) I am going to prevent that scenario by performing a single pass over the input and consuming *whole* url substrings before the other patterns get a chance at it.
  (notice: `http://example.com/@dave` and `http://example.com?asdf=1234#anchor`)
- There are two reason that I am declaring your hashtag/usertag lookup array as a constant.

  1. It does not vary, so it needn't be a variable.
  2. It enjoys global scope, so the `use()` syntax is not necessary inside of `preg_replace_callback()`.
- You should avoid adding inline styling to your tags.  I recommend assigning a class so that you can simply update a single portion of the stylesheet when you decide to amend/extend the styling at a later time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aJ3HO))

```
define('PINGTAGS', [
        '#' => 'hashtag.php?hashtag',
        '@' => 'user.php?user'
    ]);

function convert_text($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "~(?i)\bhttps?[-\w.\~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+|[@#](\w+)|U\+([A-F\d]{5})~",
        function($m) {
            // var_export($m);  // see for yourself
            if (!isset($m[1])) { // url
                return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $m[0], $m[0]);
            }
            if (!isset($m[2])) { // pingtag
                return sprintf('<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>', PINGTAGS[$m[0][0]], $m[1], $m[0]);
            }
            return "<span class=\"emoji\">&#x{$m[2]};</span>"; // emoji
        },
        $str);
}

echo convert_text(
<<<STRING
This is a @ping and a #hash.
This is a www.example.com, this is http://example.com?asdf=1234#anchor
https://www.example.net/a/b/c/?g=5&awesome=foobar# U+23232 http://www5.example.com
https://sub.sub.www.example.org/ @pong@pug#tagged
http://example.com/@dave
more http://example.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)
andU+98765more http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1
and more http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
and more http://example.com/(something)?after=parens
STRING
);
```

Raw Output:

```
This is a <a href="user.php?user=ping">@ping</a> and a <a href="hashtag.php?hashtag=hash">#hash</a>.
This is a www.example.com, this is <a href="http://example.com?asdf=1234#anchor">http://example.com?asdf=1234#anchor</a>
<a href="https://www.example.net/a/b/c/?g=5&awesome=foobar#">https://www.example.net/a/b/c/?g=5&awesome=foobar#</a> <span class="emoji">&#x23232;</span> <a href="http://www5.example.com">http://www5.example.com</a>
<a href="https://sub.sub.www.example.org/">https://sub.sub.www.example.org/</a> <a href="user.php?user=pong">@pong</a><a href="user.php?user=pug">@pug</a><a href="hashtag.php?hashtag=tagged">#tagged</a>
<a href="http://example.com/@dave">http://example.com/@dave</a>
more <a href="http://example.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)">http://example.com/more_(than)_one_(parens)</a>
and<span class="emoji">&#x98765;</span>more <a href="http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1">http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1</a>
and more <a href="http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1">http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1</a>
and more <a href="http://example.com/(something)?after=parens">http://example.com/(something)?after=parens</a>
```

Stackoverflow-Rendered Output:

This is a @ping and a #hash.
This is a www.example.com, this is http://example.com?asdf=1234#anchor
https://www.example.net/a/b/c/?g=5&awesome=foobar# 𣈲 http://www5.example.com
https://sub.sub.www.example.org/ @pong@pug#tagged
http://example.com/@dave
more [[http://example.com/more_(than)*one*(parens)](http://example.com/more_(than)_one_(parens))](http://example.com/more_(than)_one_(parens))
and򘝥more http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1
and more http://example.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1
and more http://example.com/(something)?after=parens

p.s. The hash and user tags aren't highlighted here, but they are the local links that you asked for.

Comment: If you later decide to add padding or other styling declarations, a class will not continue to bloat your html markup.  A simple `class` declaration keeps your content clean and easy to manage.  There are more reasons.  Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612483/2943403

Comment: I should wait to see if would come better answers.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that maybe you might want to write some expression somewhat close to,

```
\bhttps?:\/\/\S*\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M6BMXC/1/)

#### Match

```
$re = '/\bhttps?:\/\/\S*\b/s';
$str = 'some text before http://some_domain.com/some_link some text before  https://www.some_domain.com/some_link some text after';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "http://some_domain.com/some_link"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "https://www.some_domain.com/some_link"
  }
}
```

#### Replace

```
$re = '/(\bhttps?:\/\/\S*\b)/s';
$str = 'some text before http://some_domain.com/some_link some text before  https://www.some_domain.com/some_link some text after';
$subst = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

#### Output

```
some text before <a href="http://some_domain.com/some_link">http://some_domain.com/some_link</a> some text before  <a href="https://www.some_domain.com/some_link">https://www.some_domain.com/some_link</a> some text after
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cHs2i5/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/cHs2i5/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: How would you implement it inside my function ?

Comment: Simple and beautiful. One problem, I imagine, could be that this has unintended consequences for URLs which are followed by punctuation, as the punctuation character would be treated as part of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To recognize links I would try:

```
function convert_text($str){
   return preg_replace_callback('/\bhttps?:\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;-]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', 'compute_replacement', $str);
}

function compute_replacement($groups) {
    return '<a href="$0">$0</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My regex is not intended to validate a URL but to recognize one, the assumption being that the URL is a valid one. Let's not forget that a valid URL can have both a query string *and* a hashtag. The latter presents a problem since the current `convert_text` function looks for hashtags under the assumption they are *not* part of a URL. So, my regex will also assume that URL's will *not* contain hashtags. So, I have added an additional call to `preg_replace` as follows to the existing function:

```
function convert_text($str) {
        $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
    //type and links
        $hrefs = [
            '#' => 'hashtag.php?hashtag',
            '@' => 'user.php?user'
        ];

        $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
             return sprintf(
                 '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
                 $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
                 $matches[1],
                 $matches[0]
             );
        }, $str);

        //$result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", '\u{${1}}', $result);
        $result = preg_replace('/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/', '<span style="font-size:30px;">&#x\\1;</span>', $result);

        // the addition:
        $result = preg_replace("~\bhttps?:/(/[^/\s]+)+/?(\?[^=\s]+=[^&\s]+(&(amp;)?[^=\s]+=[^&\s]+)*)?\b~", '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $result);

        return ($result);
}
```

Test:

```
echo convert_text('#abc http://example.com https://example.com/a/b?x=1&y=2');
```

Prints:

```
<a href="hashtag.php?hashtag=abc">#abc</a> <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> <a href="https://example.com/a/b?x=1&y=2">https://examle.com/a/b?x=1&y=2</a>
```

Comment: Cool , I Will test soon.

Answer (score 0):

@tarleb no, this regex by @emma will not match that punctuation, actually will not match anything different to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in the end of the url.

RFC "Legal" characters are `[%A-Za-z0-9\-_~:\/?#\]\[@!$&'()*+,;=]`

So, that regex will not match valid urls ending in `%.-_~:/?#][@!$&'()*+,;=`, valid URLs too. So, if you want to match them but not any URL ending with `.` you should add:

`(\bhttps?:\/\/\S{4,}(?:[-_~:\/?#\]\[@!$&'()*+,;=%]|\b))`

You can also remove the `,` or any other to match as you please.

```
function convert_text($str) {
    $regex = "/[@#](\w+)/";
//type and links
    $hrefs = [
        '#' => 'hashtag.php?hashtag',
        '@' => 'user.php?user'
    ];

    $result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($hrefs) {
         return sprintf(
             '<a href="%s=%s">%s</a>',
             $hrefs[$matches[0][0]],
             $matches[1], 
             $matches[0]
         );
    }, $str);

    $result = preg_replace('/(\bhttps?:\/\/\S{4,}(?:[-_~:\/?#\]\[@!$&\'()*+,;=%]|\b))/', '<a href="\1">\1</a>', $result);

    //$result = preg_replace("/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/", '\u{${1}}', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/U\+([A-F0-9]{5})/', '<span style="font-size:30px;">&#x\\1;</span>', $result);

    return ($result);
}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M6BMXC/3)

Comment: Can you make a implementation in the function?

Comment: do you think I would have a `var` conflict because of using $result 2 times in the function?

Comment: No, no problem at all

Comment: This solution could be vulnerable to JavaScript code injection