# Custom theme datepicker element-ui in vue

Tags: css, vue-cli-3, element-ui

I have website with user can choice date_range, so i use datepicker element-ui. But datepicker default theme, how i can change that in vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, [Element-UI](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/theme) doesn't provide the function of highly customized theme, only simple customized size and color.

However, you can customize the style with the following configuration:

**`popper-class`** - custom class name for DatePicker's dropdown

**`picker-options`** - You can set custom class name by creating a `picker-options` object with **`cellClassName`** property.

You can override the default style with a custom class.

Example:

```
// template
<el-date-picker v-model="value1"
                type="date"
                popper-class="custom-date-picker"
                placeholder="Pick a day">
</el-date-picker>
```

```
// css
.custom-date-picker{
  .el-date-picker__header{
    // custom header style here
  }
}
```

Comment: i try it, but not work.

     <div class="wrap-date-picker">
      <date-picker
       v-model="daterange_filter"
       type="daterange"
       popper-class="custom-datepicker"
       range-separator="To"
       start-placeholder="Start date"
       end-placeholder="End date"
      >
      </date-picker>
     </div>

 .custom-datepicker {
  .el-picker-panel__body-wrapper{
   .el-picker-panel__body{
    background-color: #54657e;
    color: #eceff4;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: i try it, but not work.

     `<div class="wrap-date-picker">
      <date-picker
       v-model="daterange_filter"
       type="daterange"
       popper-class="custom-datepicker"
       range-separator="To"
       start-placeholder="Start date"
       end-placeholder="End date"
      >
      </date-picker>
     </div>`

 `.custom-datepicker {
  .el-picker-panel__body-wrapper{
   .el-picker-panel__body{
    background-color: #54657e;
    color: #eceff4;
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: @user8489678 Do you use sass or less?

Comment: I use scss in my style

Comment: Try `.custom-datepicker { /deep/ .el-picker-panel__body-wrapper{ .el-picker-panel__body{ background-color: #54657e; color: #eceff4; } } }`

Comment: I use sass goe mu style

Answer (score 0):

this working for me, [Element Plus](https://element-plus.org/en-US/#/en) with [Vue 3!](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html)
**In App.vue**

```
<style lang="scss">
 .el-date-editor {
   --el-date-editor-width: 40% !important;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add style inside the tag like

```
<el-date-picker  v-model="value1"
            type="date"
            popper-class="custom-date-picker"
            placeholder="Pick a day"
       -->  style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: Using inline CSS (`style` attribute) is considered [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css).