# Different Width for Image if Mobile - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries

Below you will see that I am trying to add a 40% `width` to my image if not a mobile device. However, the image is still showing with 100% width even on Desktop Devices. You can view this page here: https://www.tattiniboots.com/product/terranova/

This is the code that I am using

```php
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if (!$detect->isMobile()) {
    add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5);

    function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery()
    {
        global $product;
        $id = $product->id;
        if ($id == 5735) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="padding: 1em 2em; clear:left;">';
            echo '<center><h2>MOBILE</h2></center><img src="https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conversion-1.png">';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
} else {
    add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 5);

    function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery()
    {
        global $product;
        $id = $product->id;
        if ($id == 5735) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery" style="padding: 1em 2em; clear:left;">';
            echo '<center><h2>NOT MOBILE</h2></center><img src="https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conversion-1.png" width="40%">';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is really no reason to do this in your PHP. You can do this in CSS with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing html inside a php file is a bad idea, both for readability, and debugging. Having [inline css is also not a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css). I would honestly recommend using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)  instead of using mobile detect, because it's not 100% accurate (it doesn't recognize some phones, and you have to keep it up to date). 
With all that said, are you trying to "increase" 40% width to a 100% width image? It's not possible to have more than 100% width. You can try to increase the width of the surrounding div with the "woocommerce-product-gallery" class.
I also notice an inconsistency here:

```
if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
  ... 
   echo '<center><h2>MOBILE</h2></center><img src="https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conversion-1.png">';
}
```

It looks like it's checking if it's not mobile, and adding the mobile img, and the reverse for the else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've choosen a bad way to solve this problem.the best way is using css (media query).
you can't use "%" in html tag width.

Answer (score 0):

`width` as an attribute inside the `img` tag always has a value in pixels (it's written without the pixels, just as the number), so the way you wrote it won't work.

If you want a percentage value for width as an *inline* attribute for the `img` tag, you should use the `style` attribute. So your `img` tag should look like this:

```
<img src="https://www.tattiniboots.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conversion-1.png" style="width:40%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this solution was resolved by simple declaring the sizing options within CSS. Remember that it is also possible to add a class within php to the image you have added to further facilitate this CSS declaration