# Background image not found (404) in django

Tags: html, css, django

I intended to set a background image in the body of my HTML page and so I merrily tried following steps:

1. Set STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in the `settings.py` and pass the URL Patterns in the `urls.py`.
2. Run static deployment `python manage.py collectstatic`
3. Pass inline css in the body tag `<body style="background-image: url('{% static '34.jpg' %}');">` into the base html file.

but this all led me to this!

> GET http://localhost:7000/static/34.jpg 404 (Not Found)

As usual below are my suspects/guilt-ridden files/codes for the case:

**1. base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>HR Suite</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            header {
             background-color: #4dacff;
             padding: 30px;
             text-align: center;
             font-size: 60px;
             color: white;
            }
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="background-image: url('{% static '34.jpg' %}');">
        <header>
            <p>HR Suite</p>
        </header>
        <div class='row'>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2. settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'uploads.core'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'uploads.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
AKASH_ROOT = 'C:\\Users\\Akash\\Documents\\Test'
```

**3. urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^$', views.login_form, name='login_form'),

    url(r'^upload/$', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),

    url(r'^drop_down/$', views.drop_down, name='drop_down'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.AKASH_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Though, I am continuously trying to solve this case and find out the reason (*read culprit*) behind. But in case you can see the one, please share your thoughts. The scene is based out on `Django version 1.9.8`.

Comment: Is `34.jpg` supposed to be in static root or media root? If it is in media root, you should try openning `http://localhost:7000/media/34.jpg`

Comment: actually I copied at both directories and but both of them gave the same 404 exception

Comment: @n1rna  My document_root in urls.py was pointing at AKASH_ROOT instead of MEDIA_ROOT. Got it !

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this error while practising, here is what I did and it worked for me.
Change `<body style="background-image: url('{% static '34.jpg' %}');">`
to

```
<body style="background-image: url("static/34.jpg");">
```

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Please do not forget to mention why inline CSS is rather bad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css