# Different row background colours depending on MySQL data

Tags: php, html

I'm selecting data from mysql into an HTML table and looking for a way to change the css of the  depending on that particular row data.

So far I have had the following code:

CSS

```
    .rowColor {
    background-color: <?php $row_color ?>
}
```

PHP

```
if ($row['status'] === "approved") {
    $row_color = "green;";
} else {
    $row_color = "orange;"; 
}
```

HTML

```
<tr class="rowColor">
<td>{$row['firstName']}</td>
<td>{$row['lastName']}</td>
<td>{$row['status']}</td>
```

Currently each row will become orange regardless of what the status datas is.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you inspect "view page source"? or inspect code? Also,, try to print $row['status'] values.... looks like straight forward problem... inspecting html generated, and variable values should resolve the issue...

Comment: Everything works as it should except the colors of each <tr>

Comment: @PeterGilbertson `Everything works except my problem` won't help anyone who tries to help you. Your code is not enough for others to understand your problem. Please provide more information. For example, `for-each` loop both in PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying css to `<tr>`, you can change `background-color` inside `style` attribute as below

```
<tr style="background-color:<?php echo $row['status'] == 'approved' ? 'green' : 'orange'?>;">
<td>{$row['firstName']}</td>
<td>{$row['lastName']}</td>
<td>{$row['status']}</td>
```

Give it a try

Comment: Just to clarify the <tr> is already inside php tags. How would I go about those extra quote marks etc?

Comment: In that case you can change it like this '<tr style="background-color:'.$row["status"] == "approved" ? "green" : "orange".'";">'

Answer (score 0):

A better practice is to apply a style class. Using inline CSS is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css).

```
<tr class="<?php echo $row['status'] == 'approved' ? 'status-approved' : 'status-pending'?>;">
```

css:

```
tr.status-approved
{
   background-color:green;
}

tr.status-pending
{
   background-color: orange;
}
```