# Preferred ways to remove an element attribute or style property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let’s say this is part of my css:

```
.notif-icon {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And I have this in my html, which initially hides the element my overriding the display property of the `notif-icon` class:

```
<span id="error" class="notif-icon" style="display:none">ERROR!</span>
```

I want to make the “ERROR!” appear (when appropriate) by removing its display property override. The question is how I should do it. Any of these seems to work:

```
document.getElementById("error").removeAttribute("style");
document.getElementById("error").style.removeProperty("display");
```

However, I would rather work with element properties than calling the attribute/property functions. I tried these, none of which worked:

```
delete document.getElementById("error").style;
delete document.getElementById("error").style.display;
```

But any of these seems to work:

1. ```
   document.getElementById("error").style = "";
   ```
2. ```
   document.getElementById("error").style = undefined;
   ```
3. ```
   document.getElementById("error").style.display = "";
   ```

It *doesn’t* work to assign `undefined` to the display property.

So my primary question is which of the three working assignments I should prefer, if any. Some explanations or references to what actually happens in the different variants would also be appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer the `.style.display = ""` because it specifically targets the `display` property. Suppose you ever add another property, it will be removed, along with the `display` property, when you clear the whole style declaration, and that might not be what you want.

Comment: 1: destroys/removes any other properties set via inline-style, 2: doesn't work, 3: sets an invalid value to the `display` property, causing it to be ignored (and therefore removed). I'd suggest using the third. This is an opinion based, question though and answers are subjective.

Comment: I'd use a CSS class instead of the inline style, and then use element.classList.add / remove (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option removes the whole style attribute, so is not recommended. Second one shouldn't work. And the third one sets it to an invalid value, returning it to its default value. Of the three ones, the 3rd is the best.

Generally, you should stay away from in-line styling ([What's so bad about in-line CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css)). I'd have a class instead, that tells the element, if it should be visible or not. Something like this:

```js
const error = document.querySelector('.notif-icon');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => error.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

```css
.notif-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="error" class="notif-icon hidden">ERROR!</span>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: You give no arguments for the statement: _"Generally, you should stay away from in-line styling."_. I do agree, but it needs an explanation.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added a link to a popular stackoverflow question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Let's hope njlarsson sees, and follows, your advice. A class is indeed a lot better.